# Manage Nuget Packages issue

Tags: c#, nuget

When I remove a set of nuget packages from a project and I try to add them again using "Manage Nuget Packages" option...the **removed** packages 
still show up **selected** so I **am not able to add** them again.
How to handle this?

Comment: You might have to manually remove them from the solution (see the "repository" file in the "packages" folder under your solution). You can also just dump your solution and start a new one.

Comment: go into your /packages/ folder and delete any folders that reference the packages you removed.  Delete the same packages from packages.config.  Restart Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0):

Add them from the solution. Right-click on the soultion and select "Manage NuGet Packages for the Solution..."

Comment: read the Q again. It shows up as added in both solution and project despite removing it.

Comment: You can fix this through the [Package Manager Console](http://docs.nuget.org/docs/reference/package-manager-console-powershell-reference). If you need a primer, [look here](http://docs.nuget.org/docs/start-here/using-the-package-manager-console).